# Navigating to app in AppleTV simulator with AppleTV remote or whatever

Tags: navigation, apple-tv, tvos-simulator

I wasted lots of time trying to launch apple tv app backgrounded. How do I change focus in apple tv remote (or by any other means)? Swiping or clicking in the swipe area
of the remote either launches settings or I get a black screen (is that supposed to be
my app launched in some dilapidated state????)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can in fact use a real apple TV remote with the apple TV simulator on your Mac.

It's impossible to develop using Xcode and the simulator unless you do this.  Just grab a remote from your real-world Apple TV and go for it.

Very easy to connect it to your Mac, google.

---

*Note, extremely old remotes don't work*

Comment: Looks like it is not possible with old tv remotes (only Siri remote), just googled.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer is to connect hardware keyboard

[image]

Obviously users of a real apple tv would have a very different user
experience that I'd like to mimic using the simulator.